# heightForFooterInSection Method Not found in Xamarin(Ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin, tableview, cell

I am working on `TableView` in Xamarin. I want to add space between Two cell. so I know the one trick is Create Section and add One Cell on it. and after That Implement `heightForFooterInSection` method to add space Between Two Cell.

The `NumberOfRowsInSection` is working fine but I can't find `heightForFooterInSection` which is my space in term of my `TableView`.

Is there any alternative or Is there any other method we can do the same thing.

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Spending 2 Hour I found the Answer.

I have to add below code in My `TableCell`.

```
 public override CGRect Frame
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Frame;
            }

            set
            {
                value.Y += 4;
                value.Height -= 2 * 4;
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }
```

It will add space between Two cell.